# Change class input variable from within closures

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

The code is for a mapped regex search and replace and I'm trying to update the input string from within a closure.

The lineNumber variable will change but this.data won't change, which is a bit odd...

Anybody have a clue on how to solve this one??

Here is the code:

```js
class regexMap {
  constructor(map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  replace(str){
    this.data = str;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.map.length; i++){
      var regex = new RegExp(this.map[i][0], 'ig')
      this.data = this.data.replace(regex, this.map[i][1].bind(this))
    }
    return this.data
  }

  update(set){
    this.data = set
    return this.data
  }

  export(){
    return this.data;
  }

  getLocation(args){
    return args[args.length-2]
  }

  getLastLine(lines){
    lines = this.getPreviousLines(lines)
    lines = this.getLocation(lines)
    return lines
  }

  getPreviousLines(self){
    var lines = this.data.substring(0, this.data.lastIndexOf(self)).split('\n')
    return lines
  }

  getPrevious(lines){
    lines = this.getPreviousLines(lines)
    lines.reverse(),lines.shift(),lines.shift(),lines.reverse()
    lines = lines.join('\n')
    return lines
  }

  getLineNumber(location){
    location = this.getLocation(location)
    var location = this.data.substring(0,location)
    location = location.split('\n').length
    return location
  }

  splitLines(){
    var lines = this.data.split('\n');
    return lines
  }

  removeLines(location,amount){
    var lines = this.splitLines()
    //console.dir(lines);
    lines.splice(location, amount)
    this.update(lines.join('\n'))
    return lines
  }

  extractAll(self,args){
    return {
      data: this.export(),
      location: this.getLocation(args),
      lastLine: this.getLastLine(self),
      previous: this.getPrevious(self),
      previousLines: this.getPreviousLines(self),
      lineNumber: this.getLineNumber(args)
    }
  }
}

// EXAMPLE:

// Create a regaxMap array
var map = [
  [/FIND (.*)\n/g,function(self,str){
    // Get all arguments and variables
    var all = this.extractAll(self,arguments)
    var ln = all.lineNumber
    if(ln = 2){
      this.update('FIND Replaced'); // <-- Doesn't work
      this.removeLines(ln,1) // Will remove a line but this.data won't change
    }
    if(str != '' && str != undefined){
      return 'find(\''+str+'\');\n'
    } else {
      console.error('FIND requires a string in line: '+ln+'.')
      return ''
    }
  }],
];

console.log(new regexMap(map).replace("find something\nFIND This is, a string\nfind \n"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are using assignment instead of comparison in `if(ln = 2)` line.

Comment: Yeah but it still doesn't  solve it, you'll get the same result...